# GetAsyncKeyState randomly works in release version

Tags: c#, .net, winapi

I want to capture key presses (e.g., ctrl+WinKey or only comma). I use WH_KEYBOARD_LL hook and GetAsyncKeyState in C#. It all works fine if I run it under debugger (i.e., debugger attached no breakpoints set). However, if I run it without debugger it rarely works. The hot keys code isn't invoked - the very same code that works if under debugger.

I've noticed that if I add logging code then it works also without debugger.
It also usually works on a slower PC.

How can I resolve the problem ?

The following is code excerpt from the hook handler

```
private bool HotKeyHandler(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, WH_KEYBOARD_LL.KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT KeyInfo) {

if ((WH_KEYBOARD_LL.GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.LWin) < 0 || WH_KEYBOARD_LL.GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.RWin) < 0)) {
    if ((int)wParam == WH_KEYBOARD_LL.WM_KEYDOWN) {
            if (WH_KEYBOARD_LL.GetAsyncKeyState(Keys.ControlKey) < 0) {
                switch (KeyInfo.VkCode) {
                    case WH_KEYBOARD_LL.VK_OEM_COMMA:
                        // Some action - this doesn't work randomly ...
                    return true;
...
                }
            }

        }
    }
return false;
}


WH_KEYBOARD_LL.Initialize(HotKeyHandler);

        public static void Initialize(Func<WPARAM, LPARAM, KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT, bool> Handler) {
            HandlerI = Handler;
            KeyboardHookProcedureHandle = NativeCalls.Hooks.SetWindowsHookEx(NativeCalls.Hooks.HookType.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, KeyboardLLHandler, IntPtr.Zero, 0);
        }

        private static NativeCalls.Hooks.Procedure KeyboardLLHandler = KeyboardProcedure;

        private static LRESULT KeyboardProcedure(int MustProcessMessage, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
            if (MustProcessMessage != HC_ACTION) { return NativeCalls.Hooks.CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHookProcedureHandle, MustProcessMessage, wParam, lParam); }

            var KeyInfo = (KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            return HandlerI(wParam, lParam, KeyInfo) ? (IntPtr)1 : NativeCalls.Hooks.CallNextHookEx(KeyboardHookProcedureHandle, MustProcessMessage, wParam, lParam);
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(System.Windows.Forms.Keys vKey);

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT {
            public DWORD VkCode;
            public DWORD ScanCode;
            public DWORD Flags;
            public DWORD Time;
            public ULONG_PTR DwExtraInfo;
        }

        public const int HC_ACTION = 0;
        public const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        public const int WM_KEYUP = 0x0101;
        public const int WM_SYSKEYUP = 0x0105;
        public const int VK_OEM_COMMA = 0xBC;
        public const int VK_OEM_PERIOD = 0xBE;
        public const int VK_TAB = 0x09;
        public const int VK_ESCAPE = 0x18;

        public const int VK_1 = 0x31;
        public const int VK_2 = 0x32;
        public const int VK_3 = 0x33;
        public const int VK_4 = 0x34;
        public const int VK_5 = 0x35;
        public const int VK_6 = 0x36;
        public const int VK_7 = 0x37;
        public const int VK_8 = 0x38;
        public const int VK_9 = 0x39;

        public const int VK_N = 0x4E;
        public const int VK_W = 0x57; // Virtual-Key Codes - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx
        public const int VK_Z = 0x5A;

/*
using DWORD = System.UInt32;
using HHOOK = System.IntPtr;
using LPARAM = System.IntPtr;
using LRESULT = System.IntPtr;
using ULONG_PTR = System.UIntPtr;
using WPARAM = System.UIntPtr;
*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetAsyncKeyState` retrieves the state right at the moment you call it, not the state synchronized with other keys you care about. You already have a hook, track the Ctrl & Win key state yourself in the hook.